# ArcGIS, arcpy, SQL expression issue

Tags: arcpy

I have polygon featureclass (BookmobileLocations) which has one field (Marker, data type Text). The field Marker has values (Site 1, Site 2, Site 3...). I want to do query using Select_Analysis.The first code works fine. The second code has problem. It should be the where_clause (SQL expression) issue. What's wrong with the second one **"Marker = \'+siteName+\'"**. Where to search right SQL expression rules?

```
siteCursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor("BookmobileLocations","Marker")
for row in siteCursor:
    siteName = row[0]
    arcpy.Select_analysis("BookmobileLocations",r"C:\EsriPress\GISTPython\MyExercises\Scratch\Temporary Storage.gdb\SiteTemp3",'"Marker" = \'' + siteName + "\'")

siteCursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor("BookmobileLocations","Marker")

for row in siteCursor:
     siteName = row[0]
     arcpy.Select_analysis("BookmobileLocations",r"C:\EsriPress\GISTPython\MyExercises\Scratch\Temporary Storage.gdb\SiteTemp3","Marker = \'+siteName+\'")
```

Comment: What was the precise problem?  With an error message you should be able to search the help, here and elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first expression works because you have paired outermost single quotes (notice the sitename is black, because it is a variable and not part of the string). Your second expression does not work because sitename is between a the outermost double quote pair when it should be outside of two double quote pairs (notice that sitename is brown and therefore part of the string and no longer a variable).  The outermost double quote syntax is more elegant, because it is a shorter expression and you do not need to escape the single quotes.

This:

```
 arcpy.Select_analysis("BookmobileLocations",r"C:\EsriPress\GISTPython\MyExercises\Scratch\Temporary Storage.gdb\SiteTemp3","Marker = \'+siteName+\'")
```

needs to change to this:

```
 arcpy.Select_analysis("BookmobileLocations",r"C:\EsriPress\GISTPython\MyExercises\Scratch\Temporary Storage.gdb\SiteTemp3","Marker = '"+siteName+"'")
```

Unfortunately the suggested change by Branco will not work.  That is shown by the fact that sitename is brown in his suggestion, meaning sitename is a literal string and not a variable that completes the expression with a runtime value.

Comment: `"Marker = '{}'".format(sitename)` though honestly, the proper way to do this is with [AddFieldDelimiters](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-functions/addfielddelimiters.htm).

Comment: I use format quite often as well in my code, and it is a good practice since it minimizes the likelihood that there will be mismatched or improperly placed quotes in the template string and it converts numbers and dates to strings automatically.  However, AddFieldDelimiter does not apply to the sitename variable and to be clear should apply to the Marker portion of the string.  So it should be "{0} = '{1}'".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(r"C:\EsriPress\GISTPython\MyExercises\Scratch\Temporary Storage.gdb", "Marker"), sitename)

Comment: -Richard, ..."Marker = '"+siteName+"'"    did not work. It produced ...Invalid expression Marker == 'Site 1'.....Failed to execute(Select).

Comment: Use the expression in my last comment, but change sitename to siteName.  If the does not work something else is wrong.  Also, list the whole select tool you used for the string version

Comment: Try: arcpy.Select_analysis("BookmobileLocations",r"C:\EsriPress\GISTPython\MyExercises\Scratch\Temporary Storage.gdb\SiteTemp3","\"Marker\" = '" + siteName + "'")

Comment: -Richard, both codes you suggested work. I had typo when copying your earlier version. Do you know any good reference about SQL things like query expression? I read ArcGIS Help Desk, but not so much useful info available there...Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're missing another single quote.

```
 arcpy.Select_analysis("BookmobileLocations",r"C:\EsriPress\GISTPython\MyExercises\Scratch\Temporary Storage.gdb\SiteTemp3","Marker = \'+siteName+\'")
```

Change to:

```
 arcpy.Select_analysis("BookmobileLocations",r"C:\EsriPress\GISTPython\MyExercises\Scratch\Temporary Storage.gdb\SiteTemp3","Marker = \''+siteName+\''")
```